# Appium Ruby Page Object Model

Tags: rubygems, automated-tests, appium, pageobjects, page-object-gem

Is there any Gem (Like Site-Prism: For Web Automation Testing) which I can use in my Mobile Automation Testing project to define the screens using Page Object Model pattern.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is something I looked to in at one time
https://github.com/capitalone/screen-object